# JavaFx-14 resizeColumnToFitContent method

Tags: javafx

JavaFx-14 put this method in the TableColumnHeader, rather than in the Skin.  How does one find a TableColumnHeader from a TableColumn and a TableView?

Comment: I have been looking all over the place, and the only thing I can find is the TableColumnHeaderTest.java mentioned in the change log.  That is really rather convoluted, and I was looking for something more direct.  If there are other examples I would be grateful of any pointers.

Comment: TornaodFX has its own hachish way to go about it, and its in Kotlin but you should be able to find something to translate it back to Java. https://github.com/edvin/tornadofx/blob/jdk10/src/main/java/tornadofx/Nodes.kt

Comment: It is a shame that such things are necessary, hackish indeed.  There must be a better way!  If not perhaps one needs adding to the next available release.

Comment: In addition, looking at the TableColumnHeaderTest.java code, that approach only really works if there is only one column.  It is obvious that no-one thought about how this code would actually be used by anyone!

Comment: as you see from its signature, it's not meant (and wasn't before fx9) for public usage (aka: app code) - so you are digging in the mud and complaining about dirty hands ;) Btw, all the old tricks (use lookup, or reflection) still work. Or implement a custom skin and headers, which is rather cleanly possible how. Curious: why would you need to access the method in app code?

Comment: to answer your question in face-value: you get the header from coumn.getStyleableNode (took a moment, had to check if it's really implemented)

Comment: @JCamacho that tornado hack will fail since fx9 (that's when the method was moved off the skin into the header - where it belongs ;), see https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8151673

Comment: @kleopatra the reason I want to access this is that it is the only way of having the table fit the data, and make it all visible.  If there is another way to tell the whole table to autosize (my table is already in scrollpanes and I want this both horizontally and vertically). The only wrinkle comes when I have wrappable columns, in which case I want the text to be wrapped into multiple lines, but I layout the fixed columns first and then allocate the remaining space to the wrappable columns.   But I will try your getStylableNode idea.

Comment: I will still have to use reflection as has been pointed out because it is protected, which raises another question, why is it protected?  Yes the implementation might be slow, but it should be my choice to call it or not depending on need, rather than being imposed by making it protected.  My tables tends to be small, so performance is not an issue.

Comment: because it's not meant for public use ;) If you have special needs, the clean way to go is to subclass the skin et al stack and expose that higher need. Suspect that you are doing something wrong or hit a bug: filling to table width is supported by resizePolicy (which is buggy, though), wrappable cells are notoriously difficult because layout isn't always triggered when content changes wrapping size. Anyway, if that's your problem you are barking at the wrong tree: as suspected, smells like a xy-problem - to get help, describe the real one, how you tried to solve it and how it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

Don't know if you still need this, but if anyone else is interested, this is how I surpassed the problem in java, based on David Goodenough's scala code above.

**The class for the TableSkin**

```java
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumnBase;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.skin.NestedTableColumnHeader;
import javafx.scene.control.skin.TableColumnHeader;
import javafx.scene.control.skin.TableHeaderRow;
import javafx.scene.control.skin.TableViewSkin;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class CustomTableViewSkin extends TableViewSkin<Track> {
    private List<CustomTableColumnHeader> columnHeadersList = new ArrayList<>();

    private class CustomTableColumnHeader extends TableColumnHeader {
        /**
         * Creates a new TableColumnHeader instance to visually represent the given
         * {@link TableColumnBase} instance.
         *
         * @param tc The table column to be visually represented by this instance.
         */
        public CustomTableColumnHeader(TableColumnBase tc) {
            super(tc);
        }

        public void resizeColumnToFitContent() {
            super.resizeColumnToFitContent(-1);
        }
    }

    public CustomTableViewSkin(TableView<Track> tableView) {
        super(tableView);
    }

    @Override
    protected TableHeaderRow createTableHeaderRow() {
        return new TableHeaderRow(this) {
            @Override
            protected NestedTableColumnHeader createRootHeader() {
                return new NestedTableColumnHeader(null) {
                    @Override
                    protected TableColumnHeader createTableColumnHeader(TableColumnBase col) {
                        CustomTableColumnHeader columnHeader = new CustomTableColumnHeader(col);

                        if (columnHeadersList == null) {
                            columnHeadersList = new ArrayList<>();
                        }

                        columnHeadersList.add(columnHeader);

                        return columnHeader;
                    }
                };
            }
        };
    }

    public void resizeColumnToFit() {
        if (!columnHeadersList.isEmpty()) {
            for (CustomTableColumnHeader columnHeader : columnHeadersList) {
                columnHeader.resizeColumnToFitContent();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**And the class for the TableView**

```java
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;

public class CustomTableView extends TableView<Foo> {
    private final CustomTableViewSkin thisSkin;

    public CustomTableView() {
        super();

        setSkin(thisSkin = new CustomTableViewSkin(this));
    }

    public void resizeColumnsToFitContent() {
        if (thisSkin != null && getSkin() == thisSkin) {
            thisSkin.resizeColumnToFit();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: basically the way to go :) A couple of comments (for future readers): a) doesn't handle nested columns (which often is not needed, so just something to keep in mind) b) since fx12, there no need to keep a list of column headers, there is public api on the skin to grab the columnHeaders `getTableHeaderRow().getRootHeader().getColumnHeaders()`

Comment: also note, that headers are re-created when column's visible property is toggled, so unused headers will pile up in your list

Answer (score 1):

Well this code is Scala not Java, but for the record the code below works:-

```
    skin = new TableViewSkin(this) {
    override protected def createTableHeaderRow:TableHeaderRow = {
        new TableHeaderRow(this) {
            override protected def createRootHeader:NestedTableColumnHeader = {
                new NestedTableColumnHeader(null) {
                    override protected def createTableColumnHeader(col:TableColumnBase[_,_]) = {
                        val tableColumnHeader = new MyTableColumnHeader(col)
                        if(col == null || col.getColumns.isEmpty || col == getTableColumn) tableColumnHeader else new NestedTableColumnHeader(col)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } 
private class MyTableColumnHeader(tc:TableColumnBase[_,_]) extends TableColumnHeader(tc) {
    def resizeCol():Double = {
        resizeColumnToFitContent(-1)
        width.value
        }
    }
```

and then when I want to use it I use kleopatra's suggestion and:-

```
      val w = columns.map { col =>
            // To find the TableColumnHeader we can use column.getStyleableNode as suggested by kleopatra on StackOverflow:-
            // you get the header from coumn.getStyleableNode (took a moment, had to check if it's really implemented) – kleopatra Jul 1 at 20:46
            col.getStyleableNode() match {
                case mtch:MyTableColumnHeader => mtch.resizeCol
                case _ => col.width.get
                }
    }.sum
```

Comment: Afaics, this won't work if you have real nested columns (the top-level created in the headerRow is a singularity to get a clean header hierarchy), so you need a custom Nested that creates your custom column header as well. Disclaimer: I don't speak Scala ;)

Comment: True, but for the moment I don't need them.  Cross bridges as I need them and all that.  But hopefully those that need this now have a pattern they can follow all in one place.

Answer (score 0):

This is a *hack'ish* way of getting the `TableColumnHeader`:

```
public TableColumnHeader getTableColumnHeader(TableView<?> table, int index) {
    return (TableColumnHeader) table.queryAccessibleAttribute(AccessibleAttribute.COLUMN_AT_INDEX, index);
}
```

Or, as [@kleopatra](https://stackoverflow.com/users/203657/kleopatra) suggested, for a *non-hack'ish* approach you can do:

```
public TableColumnHeader getTableColumnHeader(TableView<?> table, int index) {
    return (TableColumnHeader) table.getColumns().get(index).getStyleableNode();
}
```

Make sure that the `TableView` is part of the scene graph.

However, the `resizeColumnToFitContent` method is protected and you won't be able to access it.

Comment: there's no reason to go hack'ish - see my comments to the question ;)

Comment: @kleopatra, point taken. Added your non-hack'ish approach to the answer ;)