# JavaFX TableView resize column to fit does not always work

Tags: javafx

In [JavaFx-14 resizeColumnToFitContent method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62679995/javafx-14-resizecolumntofitcontent-method) a method to autosize columns to fit the size of the header and the column data was estabished.

In the main this works, at least for simple columns, but when I try to use a column whose cellFactory is set to CheckBoxTableCell.forTableColumn or when I try to create my own TableCell (as it happens for a filtered combobox) all I get is the default width (of 80), which is independent of either the header width or the data width.

Obviously in the case of the CheckBoxTableCell, the cell is almost always smaller than the header, but even here the column header is truncated.  In the image below the first two columns seem to work as expected, but the Profession column has had both the header text and the row data text truncated, and in the case of the CheckBoxTableCell it is only the header (which should read "Enabled Test") which is truncated.

[image]

I presume that there is something that the default TableCell used by a simple TableColumn has that I need to add to my explicit cells, although it is has to see how I would add this to the .forTableColumn generated TableCell.

Code to show the problem with the checkbox column (in scala, sorry my Java is rather rusty these days):-

```scala
import scalafx.application.JFXApp3
import scalafx.application.JFXApp3.PrimaryStage
import scalafx.scene.Scene
import scalafx.scene.control.TableView
import scalafx.scene.control.TableColumn
import scalafx.scene.control.cell.CheckBoxTableCell
import scalafx.beans.property.BooleanProperty
import scalafx.beans.value.ObservableValue
import scalafx.collections.ObservableBuffer
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumnBase
import javafx.scene.control.skin.{NestedTableColumnHeader,TableColumnHeader,TableHeaderRow,TableViewSkin}
import scalafx.application.Platform

object TableColumnWidth extends JFXApp3 {
  override def start(): Unit = {
    stage = new PrimaryStage {  
      title = "Test Table Column Width Problem"
      scene = new Scene {
        val ob = ObservableBuffer[TableColumnData]()
        val table = new TableView[TableColumnData](ob) {
          def createDefaultSkin = new TableViewSkin(this) {
            override protected def createTableHeaderRow:TableHeaderRow = {
              new TableHeaderRow(this) {
                override protected def createRootHeader:NestedTableColumnHeader = {
                  new NestedTableColumnHeader(null) {
                    override protected def createTableColumnHeader(col:TableColumnBase[_,_]) = {
                      if(col == null || col.getColumns.isEmpty || col == getTableColumn) new FormFxTableColumnHeader(col) 
                        else new NestedTableColumnHeader(col)
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          columns ++= Seq{new TableColumn[TableColumnData,java.lang.Boolean](){
                            text = "Enabled Test"
                            cellValueFactory = { c => 
                              (new BooleanProperty(this,"Enabled",c.value.enabled) {
                                onChange{ (_,_,newValue) => c.value.enabled = newValue }
                                }).asInstanceOf[ObservableValue[java.lang.Boolean,java.lang.Boolean]]
                              }
                            cellFactory = CheckBoxTableCell.forTableColumn(this)
                            editable = true
                                resizable = false
                            }
                        }
              editable = true
          }
        root = table
        ob ++= Seq(TableColumnData("First",false),
                   TableColumnData("Second",false))
        Platform.runLater(() -> {
            val w = table.columns.map { col =>
              // To find the TableColumnHeader we can use column.getStyleableNode as suggested by kleopatra on StackOverflow:-
              // you get the header from column.getStyleableNode (took a moment, had to check if it's really implemented) – kleopatra Jul 1 at 20:46
              col.getStyleableNode() match {
                case mtch:FormFxTableColumnHeader => mtch.resizeCol() 
                case u => col.getWidth() 
                }
              }.sum + 25
            // if(width.value > w) {
            table.prefWidth = w
            table.minWidth = w
            table.maxWidth = w
            })
         sizeToScene()
        }
      }
    }
  }
class FormFxTableColumnHeader(tc:TableColumnBase[_,_]) extends TableColumnHeader(tc) {
  def resizeCol():Double = {
    resizeColumnToFitContent(-1)
    // println(s"in resizeCol for ${tc.getText()}, width ${tc.width.value}}")
    tc.getWidth()
    }
  }
class TableColumnData(var name:String,var enabled:Boolean)
```

The header in this one will be truncated to "Enabled..."

Anyone have any ideas as to what is needed?

Comment: I did not tag it Scala (or ScalaFX which is the Scala wrapper for JavaFX) because I think it is a JavaFX problem, not a Scala(FX) problem.

Comment: In FX18, this is working as expected. May be you should consider providing a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to let us know what you are trying.

Comment: I am using FX18, and I get the problem.  And there is now an example.

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned in the comments, I don't see any issues in using the `resizeColumnToFitContent` method.

Below is your example re-written in java (FX18). And it works as expected to resize the table.

[image]

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.beans.property.BooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleBooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Skin;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumnBase;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.CheckBoxTableCell;
import javafx.scene.control.skin.NestedTableColumnHeader;
import javafx.scene.control.skin.TableColumnHeader;
import javafx.scene.control.skin.TableHeaderRow;
import javafx.scene.control.skin.TableViewSkin;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class FitTableViewToColumnsDemo extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        ObservableList<Person> persons = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        persons.add(new Person("Bruce Willis", "bruce.willis@disaster.com", "Actor"));
        persons.add(new Person("Liz Truss", "liz.truss@gov.uk", "Prime Minister"));
        persons.add(new Person("Vincent van Gough", "vincent@sunflower.com", "Artist"));

        TableColumn<Person, String> nameCol = new TableColumn<>("Name");
        nameCol.setCellValueFactory(param -> param.getValue().nameProperty());

        TableColumn<Person, String> emailCol = new TableColumn<>("Email");
        emailCol.setCellValueFactory(param -> param.getValue().emailProperty());

        TableColumn<Person, Boolean> enabledCol = new TableColumn<>("Enabled Test");
        enabledCol.setCellValueFactory(param -> param.getValue().enabledProperty());
        enabledCol.setCellFactory(CheckBoxTableCell.forTableColumn(enabledCol));

        TableColumn<Person, String> profCol = new TableColumn<>("Profession");
        profCol.setCellValueFactory(param -> param.getValue().professionProperty());

        TableView<Person> tableView = new TableView<>() {
            @Override
            protected Skin<?> createDefaultSkin() {
                return new MyTableViewSkin(this);
            }
        };
        tableView.getColumns().addAll(nameCol, emailCol, profCol, enabledCol);
        tableView.setItems(persons);
        VBox root = new VBox();
        root.getChildren().addAll(tableView);
        VBox.setVgrow(tableView, Priority.ALWAYS);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setTitle("FX18 FitTableViewToColumnsDemo");
        primaryStage.show();

        Platform.runLater(() -> {
            double totalWidth = tableView.getColumns().stream().map(tc -> {
                if (tc.getStyleableNode() instanceof FormFxTableColumnHeader header) {
                    return header.resizeCol();
                } else {
                    return tc.getWidth();
                }
            }).mapToDouble(f -> f.doubleValue()).sum();
            totalWidth = totalWidth + 25;
            tableView.setPrefWidth(totalWidth);
            tableView.setMinWidth(totalWidth);
            tableView.setMaxWidth(totalWidth);
            primaryStage.sizeToScene();
        });

    }

    class MyTableViewSkin extends TableViewSkin<Person> {

        public MyTableViewSkin(TableView<Person> tableView) {
            super(tableView);
        }

        @Override
        protected TableHeaderRow createTableHeaderRow() {
            return new TableHeaderRow(this) {
                @Override
                protected NestedTableColumnHeader createRootHeader() {
                    return new NestedTableColumnHeader(null) {
                        @Override
                        protected TableColumnHeader createTableColumnHeader(TableColumnBase col) {
                            if (col == null || col.getColumns().isEmpty() || col == getTableColumn()) {
                                return new FormFxTableColumnHeader(col);
                            } else {
                                return new NestedTableColumnHeader(col);
                            }
                        }
                    };
                }
            };
        }
    }

    class FormFxTableColumnHeader extends TableColumnHeader {
        TableColumnBase tcb;

        public FormFxTableColumnHeader(TableColumnBase tc) {
            super(tc);
            tcb = tc;
        }

        public double resizeCol() {
            resizeColumnToFitContent(-1);
            return tcb.getWidth();
        }
    }

    class Person {
        private StringProperty name = new SimpleStringProperty();
        private StringProperty email = new SimpleStringProperty();
        private StringProperty profession = new SimpleStringProperty();
        private BooleanProperty enabled = new SimpleBooleanProperty();

        public Person(String name1, String email1, String profession1) {
            name.set(name1);
            email.set(email1);
            profession.set(profession1);
        }

        public StringProperty nameProperty() {
            return name;
        }

        public StringProperty emailProperty() {
            return email;
        }

        public BooleanProperty enabledProperty() {
            return enabled;
        }

        public StringProperty professionProperty() {
            return profession;
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE :**

I think I am now able to reproduce the issue if I set the columns `resizable` property to `false`. I think that should be the issue at your side as well.

[image]

If you want to set the columns to resizable `false`, I think you can remove the setting at the time of declaration and add it after the tableView width is computed (in Platform.runLater).. something like..

```
Platform.runLater(() -> {
    double totalWidth = tableView.getColumns().stream().map(tc -> {
        if (tc.getStyleableNode() instanceof FormFxTableColumnHeader header) {
            return header.resizeCol();
        } else {
            return tc.getWidth();
        }
    }).mapToDouble(f -> f.doubleValue()).sum();
    totalWidth = totalWidth + 25;
    tableView.setPrefWidth(totalWidth);
    tableView.setMinWidth(totalWidth);
    tableView.setMaxWidth(totalWidth);
    profCol.setResizable(false); \\ turn off resizable after the width is computed
    enabledCol.setResizable(false);
    primaryStage.sizeToScene();
});
```